# How to remove unwanted first parskip inside tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, amsthm, thmtools, parskip

In the example below, how do I remove the first parskip between the top edge of the `tcolorbox` environment and the first line of the theorem?

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[parbox=false]
  \begin{theorem}
    \lipsum[1-2]
  \end{theorem}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

if I use amsthm's `\newtheorem` instead of thmtool's `\declaretheorem` (commenting out `\usepackage{thmtools}`) the space disappears.

[image]

Comment: Surely you must mean `amsthm`.  `amsmath` has nothing to with theorems, only with the application of the qed box at the end of a proof that ends with a display.

Comment: Yes ofc that was a typo, fixed it now.

Comment: A fix is also needed in the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not an optimal solution, but you could remove the `parbox` option from your `tcolorbox` and then set `\parskip` inside the theorem:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{theorem}

\makeatletter
\addtotheorempostheadhook{\leavevmode\parskip\scr@parskip}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
  \begin{theorem}
    \lipsum[1-2]
  \end{theorem}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: The biggest inconvenience is that I need to do that after every `\declaretheorem`. Is there a way to patch `\declaretheorem` to automatically include that code, maybe with `etoolbox`?

Comment: @noibe, take out the optional argument: `\addtotheorempostheadhook{\leavevmode\parskip\scr@parskip}`. I shouldn't have used it to start with I think.